# console space eaten up by file contents

Tags: terminal, vi, terminal-emulator

see the example below to understand my problem ; consider my console prompt look like this

```
user@server $ ls
"I opened a file temp"
user@server $ vi temp
```

temp will open in the same window, when I close temp, I don't come back to:

```
user@server $ ls
user@server $ vi temp
user@server $
```

instead I come back to something like this

```
user@server $ ls
user@server $ vi temp
"temp file content"
"temp file content"
"temp file content"
user@server $
```

It's eating up my visible screen space, and I may end up losing some important output because of this file content.

Comment: If it's "important output" it shouldn't be in your scroll-back: it should be in a file. Cut and paste it, or pipe/tee it there in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

There is a feature in terminals called "alternate screen". It lets a program use a different virtual "screen" and restore the previous one when it exits.

You need a terminal emulator that supports this feature. Gnome-terminal, urxvt, and xterm all do. I've never seen it disabled by default, but if it is just disabled, you may be able to enable it using Xresources. If you have xterm or urxvt, then in your `~/.Xresources` or `~/.Xdefaults` file, add the following:

For xterm:

```
XTerm*titeInhibit: false
```

For urxvt:

```
urxvt*secondaryScreen: true
```

Some gui terminals may have an options panel with a check-box for enabling the alternate screen.

More resources:

http://blogmal.42.org/tidbits/titeinhibit.story

http://shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using `screen` (or `byobu`, which is an extended version of `screen` you might like better). It needs no special terminal support beyond the standard features.

You launch it like this:

```
screen
```

or

```
byobu
```

Easy!

Then it opens with a new shell. Once inside, you can open a second shell *at the same time* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, and then you can switch between then with <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>. You can repeat this to open even more at once.

You can also open vim (or anything else) in another view like this (from *within* one of the existing screen views):

```
screen vim blah
```

As an added bonus you can close the terminal (not exit the shell), log out, and when you next log in again (assuming the machine hasn't been rebooted) you can reconnect to your old session, and everything will still be as you left it:

```
screen -r
```

The downside is that you can't use the terminal's own scroll feature - you have to use `screen`'s scroll feature: hit <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, then you can page up and down, and return to normal mode with <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Use the full blown vim version, not the vim-tiny one. Both vim and vim-tiny are conveniently called from the command line using `vi` as it is a drop in replacement for the original editor. Many distributions come standard with vim-tiny.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it's technically incorrect. The OP also stated they were using `vi` not `vim`. If you make an effort to correct, or at least clarify and expand, your answer, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: `vim` is called with `vi` from the command line. Many distributions, including Ubuntu, have vim-tiny installed by default which again is simply called from the command line by typing `vi`. One of the habits of vim-tiny is the effect as described above.

Comment: Then perhaps you should include that information in your answer and help the OP understand what package they may have installed (perform `which vi` and/or `rpm -qa | grep vi`) and the behavior that can be expected.

Comment: Not all distributions use RPM package manager, so that is useless information as long as we don't know the distribution.

Comment: True. I was just providing an example of what might be useful to help the OP.